# Test if navigator.getUserMedia requires https without browser user agent sniffing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, https, getusermedia

I would like to use Javascript to determine if a browser supports webcam access (navigator.getUserMedia) over http, in the event that it doesn't I want to redirect the user to https. HOWEVER, I do not want to redirect the user to https at all if the browser supports webcam access without requiring https (firefox, for example) I want to serve the site using exclusively http. My current solution is to shiff a browser's user agent a la:

```
var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
```

My current solution will break down in theory as Firefox is likely to patch http support for webcam access out some time in the next few years.

Theres a reason for my reluctance to push https on all browsers at this point in time that I wont get into, but yes I realize that the browser world is moving in a direction that will someday require https everywhere.

```
!!navigator.getUserMedia
```

This returns true wether I'm running chrome in http or https, I would like to produce a falsey value when running http on current versions of chrome but not firefox, The reason I want to do it this way rather than user agent sniffing is because as browsers patch support for webcam access on http I want my code to adapt without needing to be patched.

In short, How can I detect the browsers that support video features in http without looking for specific browser user agents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will detect Chrome's https behavior today, without a prompt:

(Use [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nzemxxjh/) in Chrome since getUserMedia in SO snippets don't work in Chrome for some reason)

```js
if ('https:' == document.location.protocol) {
  console.log("Page is https.");
} else {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {width: {min: 2, max: 1}}})
  .then(stream => {
    log("Detection failed!");
    stream.getTracks().forEach(t => t.stop());
  })
  .catch(e => {
    switch (e.name) {
      case "NotSupportedError":
      case "NotAllowedError":
      case "SecurityError":
        console.log("getUserMedia in http is disallowed");
        break;
      case "OverconstrainedError":
      default:
        console.log("getUserMedia in http is allowed");
        break;
    }
  });
}
```

This works because Chrome today fails with `"NotSupportedError"` in https *before* it considers constraints. We're passing in impossible constraints, so in the case where http is allowed, we instead fail with an `"OverconstrainedError"`, so either way no prompt is ever shown to the user.

You'll note I'm hedging a bit, because "NotSupportedError" is not actually a valid error according to the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#dom-mediadevices-getusermedia). I *think* once Chrome updates to follow the spec, it should fail with `"SecurityError"` instead of `"NotSupportedError"`, but I'm not certain. There's a chance it would instead consider constraints first, in which case this test may stop working.

Comment: it would be great if this was in ES5

Comment: @denodster Replacing `foo => bar` with `function(foo) { return bar; }` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, I've tested this on safari, firefox, and chrome:

```
if(navigator.mediaDevices){
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).then(function(){
    //firefox, chrome in https
    alert('success!'); 
  }, function(){
    //chrome in http
    alert('failure!'); 
  });
} else {
  //safari, ie
  alert('not supported');
}
```

This does however pop up a permission bubble when run, which is not desirable, I would like to find a solution that does not bother the user in it's detection process.